# Log upstream service in nginx load balancer log

Tags: nginx, load-balancer

I have 2 nginx webservers with a nginx load balancer spliting the load.
I am trying to log to which webserver was a request sent into the log file `/var/log/nginx/access.log` but I can't find such option in [ngx_http_log_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) docs.

Any idea if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable [`$upstream_addr`](http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_addr) contains `IP:port` pairs for all visited upstreams.